# Selecting axis form multidimensional arrays with an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subset, slice

I am trying to select a subset of a multidimensional array using another array, so for example, if I have:

```
a=np.linspace(1,30,30)
a=a.reshape(5,3,2)
```

I would like to take the subset [:,0,1], which I can do by saying

```
a_subset=a[:,0,1]
```

but, is there any way to define an array/list specifying that subset and then subtract it? The idea is to do something like:

```
b=[:,0,1]
a_subset=a[b]
```

which does not work as ":" is not accepted as item ("SyntaxError: invalid syntax")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `numpy.index_exp` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html#numpy.s_)) as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(1, 30, 30)
a = a.reshape(5, 3, 2)

b = np.index_exp[:,0,1]
a_subset = a[b]
```

Comment: Equivalent expressions are `np.s_[:,0,1]` and `(slice(None), 0, 1)`